# C int array issue

Tags: c, arrays, grid, int

[my output values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUvjj.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define W 160
#define H 105

struct dungeons {
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};

void randomNumberGenerator(int seed);
void makeGameBoard(int gameBoard[W][H]);
void makeDungeonRooms(struct dungeons d[10]);
void printGame(int gameBoard[W][H]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int  gameBoard[W][H];
    //int gameBoard[160][105] = {2};

    struct dungeons d[10];

    makeGameBoard(gameBoard);
    makeDungeonRooms(d);
    printGame(gameBoard);

    return 0;
}

void randomNumberGenerator(int seed) {
    srand(seed);
}

void makeGameBoard(int gameBoard[160][105]) {
    int i;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 105; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 160; i++) {
            gameBoard[i][j] = 2;
            //gameBoard[i][j] = 2;
            /*
            if (j == 0) {
                gameBoard[i][j] = 2;
            } else
            if (j == 104) {
                gameBoard[i][j] = 2;
            } else
            if (i == 0) {
                gameBoard[i][j] = 2;
            } else
            if (i == 159) {
                gameBoard[i][j] = 2;
            } else {
                gameBoard[i][j] = 4;
            }
            */
        }
    }
    gameBoard[0][1] = 2;
    gameBoard[0][0] = 2;
    gameBoard[159][0] = 3;
}

void makeDungeonRooms(struct dungeons d[10]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < W; i++) {
        d[i].x = 0;
        d[i].y = 0;
        d[i].width = 0;
        d[i].height = 0;
    }
}

void printGame(int g[W][H]) {
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < W; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < H; j++) {
            printf("%d", g[i][j]);
            /*
            if (g[i][j] == 2) {
                printf("|");
            } else
            if (g[i][j] == 1) {
                printf("X");
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
            */
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I'm making a grid. But the first 5 rows and half of the 6th row, when printed output the value 0. I'm setting everything to 2 in the `for` loop, and even after when I try to manually change the value, it still doesn't. The last one [159][0] works but nothing in the first 5 rows and half of the 6th seem to work. They stay 0. Why?

Comment: Show us your function call?

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: The posted code is fine. Maybe you call the function in a wrong way or maybe you print the array in a wrong way. In other words - you need to post more of your code to get any help.

Comment: posted the rest of it. i have all 16800 values being printed. just the first 5 rows and half of the 6th wont change manually or in the for loop

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
void makeDungeonRooms(struct dungeons d [10]){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i< W; i++){
    d[i].x = 0;
    d[i].y = 0;
    d[i].width = 0;
    d[i].height = 0;
  }
}
```

where `#define W 160`. Accessing array out of bound can trigger **undefined behavior**. It can trigger a segmentation fault, it can remain unnoticed for a long time or alter the output of the program in very strange ways. Here, zeroing the dungeons also partly zeroed the gameBoard. Keep it that way: your game is going to be hilarious!